# NVidia GT240 Down-Clocks on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, gpu

I have a GT240 which I use primarily for BOINC (scientific computing). I run it at 100% all the time (with a tool to keep the temperature below 90 celcius). I've noticed that after some time, the GPU "down-clocks"; the GPU clock reduces from 550 to 135.

This just started recently. Is there a way to prevent this? There's no global setting to enable maximum performance, and I can't do it per executable since I need this primarily for scientific computing.

I've tried:

- Various and numerous NVidia driver versions from 260.x to 280.x
- RivaTuner (doesn't support ForceWare drivers)
- NVTray (doesn't fix the clock speed)
- MSI Afterburner (doesn't fix the clock speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread [Zotac GT240 Problem Driving Me Nuts](http://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=12920) says that this is a driver bug that is triggered by the screen-saver. The advice is :

> Go to Control panel>power options and make sure the power scheme is
>   set to always on 
> Go to Control panel>display and disable all the
>   screensavers - you can however still have the monitor power off.